I currently hold an L-1 Visa and have booked to go on holiday to the US in December. Do I need an ESTA?
I have an L1 Visa with which I have been back and forth to the US for work purposes. I have now booked a holiday to go to New York in December.
May I use my L1 visa to enter the US or do I need to apply for an ESTA?

Where is your employer based?  Specifically, are you paid your salary by a US company, or by a non-US entity.

L1 visa is employment visa and you're declaring you're coming for work purposes when using it. Since you're coming for a holiday, that would be a lie. Lying to the immigration is usually frowned upon. You should have a tourist visa/ESTA for this trip.

Note, US visas work differently from European visas. In Europe you have a C or D visa and can use it for various purposes. That's not how it works in the US. In the US visas are for application for admission (they are meaningless after being admitted), and for admission in specific status. If the visa is L1 - you're only allowed to apply for admission in L1 status using it. L1 is for employment, you're coming for tourism, which is B2. So you also need a visa allowing you to apply for admission for tourism - B1/B2 or ESTA.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Whether you need an ESTA or not, it doesn't cost much to get one , and it is safer if you have it.
There is or was an anecdote on this site from someone who had some sort of work-authorizing visa, who sought to enter for a tourist visit unconnected to the purpose of the visa, and the officer decided to admit him in the work-authorizing status.  This is helpful if, for example, your plans change, because it avoids the need to apply for change of status.
But it's not at all clear that this practice reflects an official policy of CBP, and I suspect that it does not, so you can't rule out the possibility that the officer would take the more strictly correct approach outlined in the other answer and refuse to admit you in L-1 status for a purely personal visit.  To avoid that, you can apply for ESTA.  When you arrive in the US, explain to the officer that you have an L-1 visa but you also got ESTA because you weren't sure whether you could use the L-1 for your trip, and let the officer decide how to admit you.
